# Vuejs: print object property with @ (escape special characters)

Tags: vue.js

I'm calling a service that retrieves a Json object like this:

```
data {
  author: "john",
  "@attributes": {
    value: 1
  },
}
```

I would like to print the value: 1 in HTML

```
<div>{{ data.author }}</div>
<div>{{ data.@attributes.value }}</div>
```

But I get an error:

```
invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in

    _s(data.@attributes.value)

  Raw expression: {{ data.@attributes.value }}
```

It seems the @ is a special character. How can I escape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Vuejs problem more like javascript.

You can use this to counter the problem:

```
<div>{{ data["@attributes"].value }}</div>
```